# How can we create a sidenav bar that is responsive using only angular material?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, sidebar, mdbootstrap

Can I use Angular materials 4 to create a similar behavior of the following `sidenav` example made with `mdbootstrap`: [the link shows a responsive sidenav with buttons with lists](https://mdbootstrap.com/previews/docs/latest/html/skins/indigo-skin.html).

I don't want to use `bootstrap 4` as it needs to add javascript and jQuery libraries for most of the components. And `mdbootstrap` uses jquery in some features.

If there is any other libraries, feel free to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you combine the angular material [*sidenav*](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) and [*expansion panel*](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) components, you should be able to replicate the same design and functionality.

This is a [quick example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akre5x?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html) by simply copying a [expansion panel](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dqqpbxgdnlo?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html) into a [responsive sidenav](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmjxrpxdgmx?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.html) (both examples from angular material):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akre5x?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.html